# C,C++ write on parallel port via USB adapter (LINUX)

Tags: c++, c, linux, adapter, parallel-port

as I said in the title I'm having some trouble using the parallel port on Lubuntu.. (I'm using a USB to PARALLEL adapter)
I wrote some code that works fine on my other linux PC (which has the parport):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> //sleep()
#include <sys/io.h> //outb() ioperm()

#define LPT1 0x0378
#define HIGH 255
#define LOW 0

int main() 
{
    if (ioperm(LPT1,1,1) == -1) //set LPT permissions
    {
        printf("PORTE CHIUSE, ESCO!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("PORTE APERTE SU %d\n", LPT1);
    while (1)
    {
        outb(HIGH, LPT1); //LED blinking on D0-D7
        sleep(5);
        outb(LOW, LPT1);
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work on the PC with the adapter.. I think that it is due to the different addresses of the virtual parport vs the physical one, but anyway I don't know how to address the virtual port.. 
So, what I should change in the code to make it work with the adapter? What address (if there is one) should I put into the costant "LPT1"?

Thanks in advance to everyone! ;) 
Good evening, Matteo.

Comment: _How_  does it not work?

Comment: It doesn't do anything.. the led attached to the D0 pin of the parport never lights up.. I forget to mention that the PC with the adapter runs Lubuntu on a virtualbox VM.. I don't know if the problem is due to the Vm or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have an actual parallel port on your computer there isn't anything at the I/O address 0x0378. Since you're using the a USB to parallel adapter, the parallel port is the adapter, not your PC. To the Linux kernel your USB adapter looks like a standard USB printer device. To access you'll need to go through kernel's USB printer device driver.  Unfortunately I don't know if it provides the low level access you're looking for. You can use it to print things by sending it a stream of data, but I don't think you can manipulate the state of individual pins.

After looking at the [USB Printer Class Specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbprint11a021811.pdf) it looks like it doesn't provide any way to manipulate the data pins the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! well seems there's no way out :P

Comment: @Moriduri You might be able to use a PCI or PCIe parallel card instead. These provide real parallel ports that have an actual I/O address although it's usually not one of the standard ones. I don't know if it will through a VM though, as that would require that the VM pass through the I/O requests transparently.

Comment: #Ross thank you for the reply! the problem is that I need it on a laptop.. I can't phisycally install it :( anyway I found a really old laptop from my mother and magically it has the parallel and serial port! so I'm ready to blink some led!! :P